# lua variable type nil even though i just assigned it

Tags: variables, lua, scope, local

I have a part of a lua script here:

```
local cmp = require("component")
local r = cmp.br_reactor
local e = require("event")
local unicode = require ("unicode")
local exit = false

local buffersize = 10000000

local last_tick_percent = 1

print(type(last_tick_percent))

function stored_energy()
  local rf_stored = r.getEnergyStored()
  local rf_percent = (rf_stored/buffersize)*100
  print(type(rf_precent))
  print(type(last_tick_percent))
  local delta_percent = rf_percent - last_tick_percent
  last_tick_percent = re_percent
  return rf_percent.."% ["..rf_stored.."] | "..unicode.char(916)..": "..delta_percent.."%"
end
```

The first print is not even executed for some reason. Inside the function, the first print returns `Number` while the second print returns `nil`.

Now I am getting the error `attempt to perform arithmetic  on upvalue "last_tick_percent" ( a nil value)`, obviously because `last_tick_percent` is `nil` which the `print(type(..))` showed.

But i just assigned it literally 5 lines above.

So the questions are:

1. Why is `last_tick_percent` nil and how can i fix that?
2. why is the first print not executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are assigning `re_percent` which is not declared in your script to `last_tick_percent` inside `stored_energy`. i am assuming you meant to assign `rf_percent`.

Comment: thank you very much. It's always the most obvious things :)

Comment: There's also a reference to `rf_precent` in one of the `print()` calls. Using an editor with syntax coloring can help avoid this class of error, if it is aware of scope and can color variables differently. [ZeroBrane Studio](https://studio.zerobrane.com/) does this well, and there are others. The [lua-users wiki has a page on the subject](http://lua-users.org/wiki/DetectingUndefinedVariables) too.